# Ruby on rails upload in host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application made in Ruby on rails and I want to upload it to a host which I recommend I tried heroku but my application is with mysql

Comment: I've never used it, but it looks like there's a Heroku addon via a service called ClearDB that will allow you to add a MySQL database to your app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: AWS RDS is another option. Heroku wrote an article about it: ["Configuring a Heroku Ruby app to use a MySQL RDS instance"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#configuring-a-heroku-ruby-app-to-use-a-mysql-rds-instance) They also support MariaDB. For me, RDS has had great features and uptime, but has been slow to release new MariaDB versions.

Comment: AWS EB: https://rubyplus.com/articles/5211-How-to-Deploy-Rails-5-1-API-only-Backend-App-to-Elastic-Beanstalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change database to postgresql for deploying to heroku.

Comment: and change the functionality if I change the MySQL database to postgresql